# What does the (!) mean after uptime on htop

Tags: htop

I was analyzing some web heads looking at `htop` and noticed the following

```
Uptime: 301 days(!), 23:47:39
```

What does the `(!)` mean?

Comment: @JoelDavis so the (!) doesn't mean anything else then the server has been up for 301 days?

Comment: They show the exact code in the link but yeah it's basically just saying "OMG!"

Comment: The exact point of demarcation is 100 days, though.

Comment: @JoelDavis - why not write that up as the A so we can get this closed out?

Answer (score 148, accepted):

From [htop](https://github.com/hishamhm/htop) source code, file [UptimeMeter.c](https://github.com/hishamhm/htop/blob/master/UptimeMeter.c), you can see:

```
char daysbuf[15];
if (days > 100) {
   sprintf(daysbuf, "%d days(!), ", days);
} else if (days > 1) {
   sprintf(daysbuf, "%d days, ", days);
} else if (days == 1) {
   sprintf(daysbuf, "1 day, ");
} else {
   daysbuf[0] = '\0';
}
```

I think `!` here is just a mark that server has been up for more than 100 days.

**Reference**

- http://sourceforge.net/p/htop/mailman/htop-general/?viewmonth=200707

Comment: So there's a buffer overflow after 9999 days of uptime? (buffer seems to be char[32] now)

Comment: I challenge you to keep a server running for 27 years without ever shutting it down once :)

Comment: challenge NOT accepter :))

Answer (score 200):

htop author here. Yes, as others already mentioned, it indeed shows up after 100 days of uptime.

The reason is nothing fancy, it's just an Easter egg in the software. Consider that the program is impressed with your uptime, and take it as you will. :)

Comment: It's always nice to see a definitive answer like this.

Comment: `impressed with your uptime` seems like wrong wording to me. Many standard Linux-distributions don't have live kernel patching and stuff enabled, but publish security fixes almost daily. I use this more than a warning, especially when the distribution already notifies in SSH-logins that a system restart is required.

Comment: So it's a cryptic part of the UI, that serves no more modern purpose other than to send users to StackExchange asking about it.

Comment: I currently have 908 days. Can we have two exclamation marks at 1000? ;-)

Comment: Most people worry with the (!). Can we have any of these instead? 

Answer (score 36):

`htop` shows the exclamation mark when the server has been up since 100 or more days.

While once system administrators had pride in showing long uptimes, nowadays the system has to be rebooted to be kept up to date with new kernels and some security fixes. For such reason, a long uptime is probably not a good thing and I tend to interpret the exclamation mark as a warning sign.

Comment: While your answer is succinct (and apparently correct), adding some links to relevant documentation or supporting sources would be a positive.

Comment: In some cases you can keep up to date without reboots. However issue is that after many changes you cannot be sure that system will boot up in case of unplanned reboot. So it's not a bad idea to do planned reboots for testing.

Comment: so the live patch in linux kernel 4 is not necessary? since the system has to be booted regularly for bug checking?

Comment: I use kernel care to make my kernel rebootless.