# What does the "3am" section means in manpages?

Tags: man

I found this accidentally.

I just typed `man fork`, and instead of showing the system call documentation, it showed to me an `awk` extension, however, the section page number was `3am`, instead of just `3`.

What does `3am` means?

Comment: 'Read it very early in the morning'.

Comment: My first thought was something like https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/405783/why-does-man-print-gimme-gimme-gimme-at-0030

Comment: @bmargulies And read `CPAN::Queue (3pm)` before afternoon tea; sorry, I missed the joke initially.

Answer (score 17):

It appears to be the manual page for a GNU Awk (`gawk`) *extension module*. The complete list is:

```
$ find /usr/share/man/man3 -name '*3am*' | xargs dpkg -S
gawk: /usr/share/man/man3/readfile.3am.gz
gawk: /usr/share/man/man3/inplace.3am.gz
gawk: /usr/share/man/man3/ordchr.3am.gz
gawk: /usr/share/man/man3/revoutput.3am.gz
gawk: /usr/share/man/man3/readdir.3am.gz
gawk: /usr/share/man/man3/filefuncs.3am.gz
gawk: /usr/share/man/man3/revtwoway.3am.gz
gawk: /usr/share/man/man3/time.3am.gz
gawk: /usr/share/man/man3/rwarray.3am.gz
gawk: /usr/share/man/man3/fork.3am.gz
gawk: /usr/share/man/man3/fnmatch.3am.gz
```

I would guess the `am` stands for **a**wk **m**odule.

Comment: In general, section 3 of the manual contains entries for library calls, which seems appropriate for `gawk` libraries, whereas `fork()` is carried out by the kernel and is therefore documented in section 2.

Comment: Yeah it seems that some libraries or "man page extensions" adds a postfix to the man page section number. In my system I've some prefixes like `cpp`, `ssl` or `perl`.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the middle part of the first line output by `man 3am readfile`, you'll see:

> GNU Awk Extension Modules

Now shouldn't be hard to guess from here, specifically when comparing to other first lines.